# Android: Database to JSON

Tags: android, json, gson, android-sqlite

How to generate a JSON file using a populated database. As of now, I can only retrieve them 1 at a time.

For example, I have a table of people that contains an id, first name, and last name. How can I loop through all of them and end up with a JSON file that contains all of the people?

```
[
    {"id":1,"firstName":"Johnny","lastName":"Storm"},
    {"id":2,"firstName":"Sue","lastName":"Storm"},
    {"id":3,"firstName":"Reed","lastName":"Richards"},
    {"id":4,"firstName":"Ben","lastName":"Grimm"}
]
```

Comment: Please learn `first how to deal with JSON in Android?` if you search in _Google_ you will get enough info. so use that one

Comment: use `android.util.JsonWriter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cursor to get all the data in database then use

```
       JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonArray();
       cursor.moveToNext();
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
          JsonObject jsonObject=new JsonObject();
          jsonObject.put("id",cursor.getInt(cursor.getIndex(<your id column name>)))
       jsonObject.put("firstName",cursor.getString(cursor.getIndex(<your firstName column name>)))
         //Do same for all the other columns
        jsonArray.add(jsonObject);
      }
```

Now your JSONArray will be [{"id":1,"firstName":"Johnny","lastName":"Storm"},{"id":2,"firstName":"Sue","lastName":"Storm"},{"id":3,"firstName":"Reed","lastName":"Richards"},{"id":4,"firstName":"Ben","lastName":"Grimm"}]

Comment: This did it. Thank you!